# How do I Insert Data in Mysqlicous Table?

Tags: mysql, tags

I am a little stuck and need help.

I already have the **items table** filled with data,
now where I am is stuck is this:

I want to add Tags to the existing urls.

What do i need to do if I have a url and the corresponding tags?

I don't know how the INSERT INTO is with a foreign key.

**Any ideas?**

I have a MySQL Database like this (Mysqlicious Schema):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item2tag` (
    `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`tag_id`),
    KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` ( 
    `vidid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vidurl`   varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    `vidimgdir` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `vidname`  varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`vidid`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `vidurl` (`vidurl`) )
    ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1782 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
    `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tag_text` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `tag_text` (`tag_text`(255)))
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then obtain the id (vidid) of the URL for which you want to add tags.

Now, for each tag, check if it exists already in the tags table. If it doesn't, add it to said table. Then do the following:

```
INSERT INTO item2tag (item_id, tag_id) VALUES (x, y)
```

The values should speak for themselves.